# Access flutter::TextureRegistrar from native app code instead of plugin

Tags: c++, flutter, flutter-plugin, flutter-windows

I want to write native windows cpp code for my application.

The "normal" way would be to write a plugin and include that in my application, right?

I was wondering if it would be possible to write the native code directly inside the windows folder of my app without creating a separate plugin.

I already managed to create a MetodChannel in `windows/runner/flutter_window.cpp`

```cpp
bool FlutterWindow::OnCreate() {
// [...]
  RegisterPlugins(flutter_controller_->engine());
  initMethodChannel(flutter_controller_->engine());
  SetChildContent(flutter_controller_->view()->GetNativeWindow());
// [...]
}

void initMethodChannel(flutter::FlutterEngine* flutter_instance) {
  const static std::string channel_name("my_channel_name");

  auto channel = std::make_unique < flutter::MethodChannel<>>(
    flutter_instance->messenger(), channel_name,
    &flutter::StandardMethodCodec::GetInstance()
  );

  channel->SetMethodCallHandler([](const auto& call, auto result)
    {
      handleMethodCall(call, std::move(result));
    });
}
```

However, now I need to access the `flutter::TextureRegistrar *texture_registrar`.

This would usually be available in the Plugins `RegisterWithRegistrar(flutter::PluginRegistrarWindows *registrar)` method like this:

```cpp
registrar->texture_registrar()
```

Now how can I access that `texture_registrar` if I am not in a Plugin?